# Can I use text when using functions? Or only numbers?

Tags: python, function

Let me just start off by saying that I'm very new to programming, I'm pretty sure this is like my fourth time sitting down and learning stuff, so well, I'm not even sure the question sounds right.

So I watch beginner tutorials for Python by CS Dojo on YouTube, I'm on the third video, it's about functions. Watching tutorials I pause the video a lot and try to experiment a little bit to truly understand what I'm working with. So it went all good when I would play around with numbers. Like here:

```
def function(x):
    return x+5
a = function(10)
print(a)
```

(Not sure if I pasted the code well, sorry)

But then I tried to do something with words to see if it could work:

```
def function(name):
    return ("Hi ")
b = function(Oskar)
print(b)
```

And it doesn't, I get an error like this:

```
NameError: name 'Oskar' is not defined
```

Do these kind of codes only work with numbers? Or did I do something wrong? I wanna understand this so I'd like someone to explain it to me, considering that I'm a beginner and don't understand a lot of the words programmists use here.

Comment: No, they also work with text, but if you write `function(Oskar)` it is not, that you pass the text `Oskar` but the object that is referenced by the NAME `Oskar`. But you haven't defined `Oskar` before. That's why you get the error. If you want to pass the text `Oskar`, you have to call it like `function("Oskar")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oskar without quote is treated as an identifier not a string. Use "Oskar" or 'Oskar'

String always have to be encapsulated in a double("") or a single('') quote

```
def function(name):
    return ("Hi " + name)
b = function("Oskar")
print(b)
```

Or use this one, in future it will come in real handy

```
def function(name):
    return (f"Hi {name}")
b = function("Oskar")
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Oskar` is a variable.  `'Oskar'` and `"Oskar"` are strings (note the quotes).

In other words, any of the following will work:

```
b = function('Oskar')
```

```
b = function("Oskar")
```

```
my_name = 'Oskar'
b = function(my_name)
```

```
my_name = input('What is your name? ')
b = function(my_name)
```

(Along with an infinite number of other examples, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

```
name = "oskar"

def function(name):
   return ("Hi " + name)
b = function(name)
print(b)
```

Oskar is not a string, but undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `Osakar` python interpreter expects a variable which is not defined in your case.

Please note that `Oskar` is different from `'Oscar'`. The first is a variable (that must be defined first). While the latter is a `string`.

Even if you use sting `'Oscar'` you cannot use it with your function. Because the `+` does not work between a string and an integer.